# Button change color on click jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've this code to change a color of a button on click:

```
$('.fav').live('click', function(e) { 

  $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "b" });

});
```

How can I return to normal color (theme c) by clicking the button again?

Is there any way to see the state of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has to be live then you could just make your own toggle:

```
$('.fav').live('click', function() {
    var dotoggle = $(this).attr("dotoggle");
    if ( dotoggle == "1"  ) {
        $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "c" });
        $(this).attr("dotoggle","0");
     }
     else {
        $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "b" });
        $(this).attr("dotoggle","1");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle of a custom toggle example: http://jsfiddle.net/PLx8v/3/

Comment: Can you give me and sample please?

Comment: Has to be .live() because the buttons are loaded via ajax into a list. The solution does not work.