# Conflict class button jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list that loads multiple buttons via ajax and each button have the class quickList.

When I click on one of these buttons will change color. Clicking it again returns to original color, like this:

```
$('.quickList').live('click', function(e) { 

    var toggle = $(this).data('press');
    if ( toggle == "true" ) {
        $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "b" });
        $(this).data("press","false");
    }
    else {
        $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: "a" });
        $(this).data("press","true");
    }

});
```

The problem is that having more than one button, they come into conflict. If I click a button it changes color, and if I click another button than it removes the color of the first (for the starting color) and put that color on the button clicked recently.

What I want is that the buttons were independent, but this conflict is happening, how can I fix?

Comment: FYI jQuery's `live` function is deprecated. You should use jQuery's `on` function.

Comment: check this question. Its similar to your question




http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386601/button-change-color-on-click-jquery-mobile

Comment: It does not solve the issue. The jQuery Mobile can not keep more than one button with a different color.